# Not able to install managed package in sandbox

Tags: community, managed-package, mydomain

I am getting the below error message while tried to install the Parley Pro package:

> Missing Organization Feature: CommonCsp

There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.

**Note** : I have already enabled My Domain and Communities.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

[image: Parley Pro Installation Error]

Comment: Do you have community enabled?
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019TnxQAE

Comment: Yes, I have already enabled the community.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a change in CSP settings in this month and more strict settings are applied, it is better to contact package provider apparently they are not ready yet.

Please check following documents:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_security_csp_overview.htm&type=0

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_security_csp_scriptlevel.htm&type=5

> What Do I Need to Do and When?
>
> To make sure that your community works as expected, the “Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Any Third-party Host” setting maintains the same security level as before Winter ‘19.
>
> However, in Spring ‘19 (February 2019), Strict CSP becomes the standard CSP setting for all new communities. And in Winter ‘20 (October 2019), the current default setting is being removed for existing communities. Consider the level of security your community requires, and decide when to take the required steps.